# using lodash instead of angular.forEach for array of arrays

Tags: angularjs, lodash

Here is my example array

```
var studentId= 2;
var students = [
[{id:1,C:40,PHP:50},{id:2,C:60,PHP:70},{id:3,C:80,PHP:90}]
[....]
[...]
]
```

Currently i am matching the studentId against students as

```
_.forEach(students,  function(student){
_.forEach(student, function(st){
if(st.id === studentId){
//do something
}
});

})
```

How can i achieve it with simple lodash commands. The goal is to avoid two forloops.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have an array of arrays of objects. you cannot skip the second loop. if you just need to find a user with a specific id maybe you have to remap all students to a hash with their id as the key

Comment: @eltonkamami you can, by flattening it first

Comment: @uzilan you are right. lodash specific code as OP asked. i think the performance will be awful if this is done too frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just need to find a user with a specific id maybe you have to remap all students to a hash with their id as the key

this can be done like so

```
students = stundents.reduce( result, studentRow => {
  studentRow.forEach(student => result[student.id] = student);
  return result;
}, {});
```

now students is an object of { 'studentid': 'student obj'}
find if student exists with a simple check

```
var studentId= 2;
if(students[studentId]){
  //student exists
}
```

Or you could deep flatten your array and then run a `Array#filter` on the result

```
var students = _.flattenDeep(students);
var studentFound = students.filter( student => student.id == studentID).length;
if(studentFound){
  //student found, do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I went with reduce option

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!_.isNil(_.find(students, { 'id': studentId }))) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Why does this answer start with "Or"?

Answer (score 0):

And here's yet another way:

```
var s = _.chain(students)
        .flatten()
        .find({'id': studentId})
        .value();
```